# How to speed up selected to active texture baking

Tags: texture-baking

At the moment I am doing a lot of texture baking heavy work at the moment and it has got to the point where this is the slowest part of my workflow.

I'm aware of the obvious things like texture and mesh resolution but I was wondering if there was something I'm overlooking, though this may not be the case.

Comment: If you don't want to bake the ligths, you can decrease the render samples to 1.

Comment: Please describe what your workflow is, so we can point out what may be wrong. It's hard to guess without more info.

Comment: I'm baking textures from a high poly photoscan mesh to a low poly retopologised mesh. there may be nothing I can do to speed it up due to the number of vertices involved but I thought there might be something I had overlooked.